# How to handle a lot of condition matches in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, rest, express

I am writing the API in express js, there is a few conditions, if they are matched I try to response back the data. So the problem is if two conditions matched, my codes are responding two times, can i stop responding another conditions after one time sent? Since I came from PHP background, this node js logic is really different.

I still try to use res.end() but if the another condition is match, its keep responding.I can't write simply if else conditions statement because there are different type of conditions.

Please take a look my codes, if you can help me out this problem, really appreciated.

```
exports.createBooking = (req, res) => {
// Save Order to Database
console.log("Processing func -> Create Booking");
// console.log(req.body);
const business_code = 'Test' + new Date("03/25/2015") + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999999999) + 1 ;
const locker_station_id = req.body.locker_station_id || '';
const reference_id = req.body.reference_id || '';
console.log(locker_station_id);
const locker = db.sequelize.query(`SELECT * FROM ems_device where locker_station_id="${locker_station_id}"`,{  plain: true,type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
.then(locker => { // data is equal to the result of line 1.
// console.log(locker);
    if(locker){
        // console.log(locker);

        if(locker.status == 0){
            res.status(422).json(ResponseFormat.error(
            'locker_station_offline',
            reference_id,
            422
            ))
        }
        else if(locker.status == 2){
            res.status(422).json(ResponseFormat.error(
            'locker_station_retired',
            reference_id,
            422
            ))
        }
        getLockerboxCategory(req, res);
        const locker_box_category = req.locker_box_category;
        const drawer_resource_info = db.sequelize.query(`SELECT * FROM ems_drawer_resource_info  where device_number="${locker.device_number}" and drawer_status=0`,{ type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
        .then(drawer_resource_info => { // data is equal to the result of line 1.
            if(drawer_resource_info.length == 0){
                res.status(422).json(ResponseFormat.error(
                'insufficient_capacity',
                reference_id,
                422
                ))
            }

        });
    }
});
}
function getLockerboxCategory(req, res){
// console.log(req.body.parcel_length);
const parcel_length = req.body.parcel_length || 0;
const parcel_height = req.body.parcel_height || 0;
const parcel_width  = req.body.parcel_width || 0;
const parcel_weight = req.body.parcel_weight || 0;

const small_box_length = 43;
const small_box_height = 8;
const small_box_width = 47;

const medium_box_length = 43;
const medium_box_height = 19;
const medium_box_width = 47;

const large_box_length = 43;
const large_box_height = 28;
const large_box_width = 47;

if(parcel_height < small_box_height && parcel_width < small_box_width && parcel_length < small_box_length){
    // small box
   req.locker_box_category = 3;
   req.locker_box_cost = 1;
}
else if(parcel_height < medium_box_height && parcel_width < medium_box_width && parcel_length < medium_box_length )
{
    //medium box
   req.locker_box_category = 2;
   req.locker_box_cost = 1.5;
}
else if(parcel_height < large_box_height && parcel_width < large_box_width && parcel_length < large_box_length )
{
    //large box
   req.locker_box_category = 1;
   req.ocker_box_cost = 2;
}else{
   res.status(422).json(ResponseFormat.error(
                'parcel_is_too_large',
                req.reference_id||'',
                422
                ));
    res.end();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to NodeJS async environment. When using `res.json` the response will be written and the stream will end, there is no use of `res.end()` when using `res.json`.
Use `res.json` when you have everything you need.

Based on your code, you could have created an else branch after the `locker.` statements:

```js
exports.createBooking = (req, res) => {
  // Save Order to Database
  console.log("Processing func -> Create Booking");
  // console.log(req.body);
  const business_code = 'Test' + new Date("03/25/2015") + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999999999) + 1;
  const locker_station_id = req.body.locker_station_id || '';
  const reference_id = req.body.reference_id || '';
  console.log(locker_station_id);
  const locker = db.sequelize.query(`SELECT * FROM ems_device where locker_station_id="${locker_station_id}"`, {
      plain: true,
      type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    })
    .then(locker => { // data is equal to the result of line 1.
      // console.log(locker);
      if (locker) {
        // console.log(locker);

        if (locker.status == 0) {
          res.status(422).json(ResponseFormat.error(
            'locker_station_offline',
            reference_id,
            422
          ))
        } else if (locker.status == 2) {
          res.status(422).json(ResponseFormat.error(
            'locker_station_retired',
            reference_id,
            422
          ))
        } else {

          let lockerBoxStatus = getLockerboxCategory(req, res); // you need to know the status of this method, go and check getLockerboxCategory

          // the stream will output the JSON if you reach the else branch, but make no mistake, the javascript is not done, the following lines will be evaluated.
          if (lockerBoxStatus) { // if this is 0, then you will not get a write error, because getLockerboxCategory will close the stream.

            const locker_box_category = req.locker_box_category;
            const drawer_resource_info = db.sequelize.query(`SELECT * FROM ems_drawer_resource_info  where device_number="${locker.device_number}" and drawer_status=0`, {
                type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
              })
              .then(drawer_resource_info => { // data is equal to the result of line 1.
                if (drawer_resource_info.length == 0) {
                  res.status(422).json(ResponseFormat.error(
                    'insufficient_capacity',
                    reference_id,
                    422
                  ))
                }

              });

          }


        }

      }
    });
}

function getLockerboxCategory(req, res) {
  // console.log(req.body.parcel_length);
  let status = 1; // assuming 1 by default
  const parcel_length = req.body.parcel_length || 0;
  const parcel_height = req.body.parcel_height || 0;
  const parcel_width = req.body.parcel_width || 0;
  const parcel_weight = req.body.parcel_weight || 0;

  const small_box_length = 43;
  const small_box_height = 8;
  const small_box_width = 47;

  const medium_box_length = 43;
  const medium_box_height = 19;
  const medium_box_width = 47;

  const large_box_length = 43;
  const large_box_height = 28;
  const large_box_width = 47;

  if (parcel_height < small_box_height && parcel_width < small_box_width && parcel_length < small_box_length) {
    // small box
    req.locker_box_category = 3;
    req.locker_box_cost = 1;
  } else if (parcel_height < medium_box_height && parcel_width < medium_box_width && parcel_length < medium_box_length) {
    //medium box
    req.locker_box_category = 2;
    req.locker_box_cost = 1.5;
  } else if (parcel_height < large_box_height && parcel_width < large_box_width && parcel_length < large_box_length) {
    //large box
    req.locker_box_category = 1;
    req.ocker_box_cost = 2;
  } else {
    status = 0;
    res.status(422).json(ResponseFormat.error(
      'parcel_is_too_large',
      req.reference_id || '',
      422
    ));
    //res.end(); // you don't need this `.json` will output+end the stream

  }
  return status;
}
```

PS: Make sure all your statements are covered by a `res.json` or `res.end()` where you consider it's apropiate to end the stream, or else the webserver will hang. And read about the `next` parameter from middlewares `app.use((req, res, next)=> next(); )`, you might need it when you want to jump on the next middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking to much into your code id suggest a switch statement. It will allow you to `break;` out of the statement once a condition is met. They should work like they do in PHP but here are the docs just in case https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp . If switch isn't working you could probably just return out of the function once a condition is met.

Comment: This should probably be a comment rather than an answer.  I suspect you haven't got comment privileges yet.

Comment: you know it ^^^